# DB2 find tables that reference my table

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

[db2-as400] I have a table `ENR_DATA` that has column `EnrollmentID` as a primary key. This column is referred by many tables as a "foreign key". Is there a way to list down all those tables who refer to `EnrollmentID` of `ENR_DATA` table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few catalog views that each give just a part of the answer, and you have to join them all together.

- SYSCST provides a list of constraints with the constrain type. From here we can select out Foreign Key constraints. TABLE_NAME in this table is the table that contains the foreign key.
- SYSKEYCST provides a list of columns for a given Foreign Key, Primary Key, or Unique constraint along with the ordinal position of the column in the key, and the associated table name.
- SYSREFCST provides the name of the Primary or Unique Key constraint that is referenced by a given Foreign Key Constraint.

From these three tables we can write the following SQL:

```
select cst.constraint_schema, cst.constraint_name,
       fk.table_schema, fk.table_name, fk.ordinal_position, fk.column_name, 
       pk.table_schema, pk.table_name, pk.column_name 
  from qsys2.syscst cst
    join qsys2.syskeycst fk 
      on fk.constraint_schema = cst.constraint_schema 
        and fk.constraint_name = cst.constraint_name
    join qsys2.sysrefcst ref 
      on ref.constraint_schema = cst.constraint_schema 
        and ref.constraint_name = cst.constraint_name
    join qsys2.syskeycst pk 
      on pk.constraint_schema = ref.unique_constraint_schema 
        and pk.constraint_name = ref.unique_constraint_name
  where cst.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
    and fk.ordinal_position = pk.ordinal_position
    and pk.table_name = 'ENR_DATA'
    and pk.column_name = 'ENROLLMENTID'
  order by cst.constraint_schema, cst.constraint_name;
```

This will get you the table names that reference 'ENR_DATA' via foreign key. Note I have ENROLLMENTID in all upper case. That is how DB2 for i stores all column names unless they are quoted using "".

Answer (score 0):

DB2 on IBM i (AS 400) offers a [list of all system tables, the system catalog](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcatalogtbls.htm). It is the place where metadata is stored. One of the views, [SYSCST, is the view with all constraints](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcatsyscst.htm), the view [SYSCSTCOL](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcatsyscstcol.htm) has information about the constraint columns, and [SYSCSTDEP](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcatsyscstdep.htm) stores the dependencies.

So you would query SYSCST, SYSCSTCOL and SYSCSTDEP for finding the details.

Comment: I queried both tables. I can see the constraints but I can not relate them with each other. I have tables PRIMARYTABLE (EMPID is primary key) and OTHERTABLE (EMPID is the column that refers to EPMID/PRIMARYTABLE). Querying SYSCST and SYSCSTCOL just gives information about the constraints EPMID_PK and OTHER_FK. It does not gives info that OTHERTABLE is referring to PRIMARYTABLE (EMPID). Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: I don't have a system for testing, but there is another table: SYSCSTDEP. It records the dependencies. http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcatsyscstdep.htm

Comment: Tried this as well. no go :(

Comment: Are you sure that there are FK relationships that are defined as referential constraints?

Comment: yeah I created the tables myself

Comment: `SYSCSTCOL` and `SYSCSTDEP` do not provide the information required. `SYSCSTCOL` provides table and column names for a given constraint, but no ordering information. `SYSCSTDEP` tells us the tables that a constraint is dependent on, but for a foreign key constraint, that dependency is simply the table that contains the foreign key, not the table the foreign key refers to.